# How to pull user interface XML from emulator with ADB and UiAutomator

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, android-uiautomator

This question has not been answered specifically for the emulator as far as I can tell, and I have not found a prior question with a correct solution for my situation:

I shell in and dump the xml

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell uiautomator dump /view.xml
```

and when I try to pull the dump

```
adb -s emulator-5554 pull /view.xml
```

I get message

> adb: error: failed to stat remote object '/view.xml': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

I dumped to the `sdcard` and was able to pull the dump

I run commands

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell uiautomator dump /sdcard/view.xml
adb -s emulator-5554 shell pull /sdcard/view.xml
```

and I get expected message

> /sdcard/view.xml: 1 file pulled. 0.2 MB/s (6478 bytes in 0.027s)